# Existe alguma forma que permita usar os botões de volume para navegar pelo site?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o meu website que no computador, ao carregar no Enter, ele vai movimentando-se pelo site, mas por telemóvel, como não tem tecla Enter, gostaria que o utilizador pudesse dar scroll com o botão do som.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cara, pelo meu conhecimento não é possível 
Você teria que ter uma permissão especial para acessar o hardware, não é uma coisa que você vai conseguir em uma plataforma web

Comment: Entendo o que disse, irei aguardar mais por outras respostas. Se não houver mesmo solução, irei dar esta resposta como aceite.

Answer (score 2):

Veja essa pergunta no `StackOverflow` em inglês

> Is it possible to bind to hardware buttons of mobile device using
>   jQuery mobile?

***É possível vincular os botões de hardware do dispositivo móvel usando jQuery mobile?***

A resposta aceita:

> Short answer is no, you can't do that with a jQuery Mobile only.

***A resposta curta é não, você não pode fazer isso com somente Jquery Mobile***

Na resposta ele diz ser possível utilizando o Phonegap/Cordova Framework... Mas ai estaríamos falando de você desenvolver seu site em formato de app, que imagino que não é o que você quer.

[Pergunta original em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293287/bind-to-mobile-device-hardware-buttons)